# How should developers go about managing complex plural words with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm playing with `pluralize` at the command line, and it's beginning to scare me.

Multiples of *leaf* is *leafs* (not *leaves*)
Multiples of *cactus* is *cactus*- not *cacti*, or even *cactuses*. *Radius* becomes *radius* instead of *radii*

Yet it correctly gets *women*, *octopi*, *knives*, and *errata* (the finer things in life).

As I understand it, ActiveRecord uses the same pluralize method that I'm using. And from my tests, it seems that if made enough tables without thinking, you would eventually run into a problem where you couldn't locate the proper table because you were expecting the plural to be different.

Is the conventional recommendation to just test all plurals in the command line, and make a note of what the table will be called? Or do most developers just label something as `uncountable` when it gets fuzzy?

Side note- no `ActiveRecord` tag??

Comment: (How often do you name a table cactus?) There is a class that handles this and you can customize it for specific words: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html

Comment: Oh, that's just what I needed. You should post this as an answer so I can accept it as a solution.

Comment: Question is a bit borderline off topic here on Programmers.SE, so I will go without those rep points :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add new inflection rules as needed

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'cactus', 'cacti'
end
```